# Getting issue with nginx ingress controller

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm getting issue with nginx ingress
Error: invalid virtual server or virtual server route

How to fix this above error?

Comment: Edit your post and include the Nginx configuration files.

Comment: @John Issue resolved

Comment: Please edit your post to describe the problem with enough details to be correctly answered. An answer to an poorly formed question limits it value. I am voting to close this question due to low quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [Blog](https://www.blinkops.com/blog/troubleshooting-your-nginx-ingress-controller) by Patrick Londa, to check the  Error: invalid virtual server or virtual server route, you need to utilize the controller logs, the generated configuration file, and check the events for the VirtualServer and VirtualServerRoute resources.

**Check Events of VirtualServer and VirtualServerRoute Resources**:

> You can check events for a VirtualServer resource with this command:
>
> ```
> kubectl describe vs <VS-resource-name>
> ```
>
> You can check events for a VirtualServerRoute resource with this
> command:
>
> ```
> kubectl describe vsr <VSR-resource-name>
> ```
>
> Similar to checking the events of an Ingress resource, if you are
> looking for normal events with the reason AddedOrUpdated to signal
> that the configuration was successfully applied.

Refer to this [gitlink](https://github.com/wallarm/ingress-plus/blob/wallarm/docs/virtualserver-and-virtualserverroute.md) for more information about VirtualServer and VirtualServerRoute Resources

Comment: @Ruthew If the issue still persists As john Hanely mentioned edit your post and include the Nginx configuration files.

Comment: I will go through your answer and try in my environment.If still issue persists I will add nginx configuration files in my question

Comment: Thanks for your answer Issue fixed